# pandas staggered transform based on date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas df which contains daily average tempreature of 3 countries:

| date | country | temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/19 | US | 18 |
| 1/1/19 | GB | 21 |
| 1/1/19 | AU | 26 |
| 2/1/19 | US | 19 |
| 2/1/19 | GB | 19 |
| 2/1/19 | AU | 30 |
| 3/1/19 | GB | 16 |
| 3/1/19 | AU | 30 |
| 4/1/19 | GB | 20 |
| 4/1/19 | US | 20 |

I am trying to create a transformation whereby I can arrnage all the countries in a separate row based on the date, taking into account missing values like so:

| date | US | GB | AU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/19 | 18 | 21 | 26 |
| 2/1/19 | 19 | 19 | 30 |
| 3/1/19 |  | 16 | 30 |
| 4/1/19 | 20 | 20 |  |

What would be the fastest way to acheive this? Is there a fatser way with numpy?

Comment: `df.pivot('date', 'country', 'temp')`

Comment: you can also use - `df.pivot(*df)`

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you!